# wordpress conditional statements

Tags: wordpress, widget, parent-child, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get this logic to work in WordPress Widget Logic:
Widget displays if it's NOT the homepage OR NOT the page 86 OR NOT if it's a child of page 86.

```
!is_home ||  !is_page('86') ||  !is_child('86')
```

I've added this function to functions.php:

```
function is_child($parent) {
  global $post;
  return $post->post_parent == $parent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
(!is_home() && !is_page(86) &&  !is_child(86))
```

`is_home()` is a function. And to check the pages I suggest using a integer not a string.
And the overall `( )` is just a safety measure. Maybe you can leave them out, I'm not sure.
Not tested.

Comment: thanks janw for the reply. However, the widget still prints out to all the pages

Comment: would this function be more appropriate: `function is_tree( $pid ) {      // $pid = The ID of the page we're looking for pages underneath
    global $post;               // load details about this page

    if ( is_page($pid) )
        return true;            // we're at the page or at a sub page

    $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
    foreach ( $anc as $ancestor ) {
        if( is_page() && $ancestor == $pid ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;  // we arn't at the page, and the page is not an ancestor
}`

Comment: Does this work if you remove the is_child? also turn on WP_DEBUG to check for errors. Maybe you can't use `is_child` here

Comment: In the case of the second function I use: '!is_home ||  !is_page('86') ||  !is_tree('86')'

Comment: BTW - I also tried using the reset query without luck: `wp_reset_query()`

Comment: See my edit try `&&`: it can't be home AND it cant be 86 AND it cant be a child of that